# Has anyone seen this space before? Does it have a name?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

See the space below (the set taken as a subspace of the plane).

[image]

It sort of looks like a [comb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space), but with the wrap-around portion added, and the lower left corner removed.

What would be a good name for this?

Comment: I met this space once when I was in a pub in Bonn. But we didn't really talk much, so I didn't catch its name.

Comment: Never seen it. "Hooked comb space"?

Comment: Give it a name, see if it catches up. Miranda sounds nice, I guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone :)

Comment: I settled on "the combover".